# Smart pointers with SDL

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, sdl-2, unique-ptr

For my game should I use a raw pointer to create `SDL_Window`, `SDL_Renderer`, `SDL_Texture` etc. as they have specific delete functions

```
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
```

or should I add a custom deleter when I create a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` and if so how would I do this with SDL types?

Comment: What does the last sentence mean - *how would I do this with SDL variables*? Are you asking how to go about creating a `unique_ptr` that'll automatically destroy some `SDL_*` object?

Comment: Sorry for bad english I should have read through it again. What I meant is how do I create a unique_ptr to handle a SDL_Window/Renderer/Texture etc.. because they all have different ways to be deleted. Or should I just use a raw pointer as it would not make much difference as I know where they should be deleted.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could create a functor that has several overloaded `operator()` implementations, each of which call the correct destroy function for the respective argument type.

```
struct sdl_deleter
{
  void operator()(SDL_Window *p) const { SDL_DestroyWindow(p); }
  void operator()(SDL_Renderer *p) const { SDL_DestroyRenderer(p); }
  void operator()(SDL_Texture *p) const { SDL_DestroyTexture(p); }
};
```

Pass this as the deleter to a `unique_ptr`, and you could write wrapper functions if you wanted to, to create the `unique_ptr`s

```
unique_ptr<SDL_Window, sdl_deleter>
create_window(char const *title, int x, int y, int w, int h, Uint32 flags)
{
    return unique_ptr<SDL_Window, sdl_deleter>(
             SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, w, h, flags), 
             sdl_deleter());
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Praetorian that is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Praetorian Where would one put this in a large program?