# Confused using unique_ptr and a custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter for `SDL_Surface` type. This is only an example using `int` type, but I hope you get the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

typedef int SDL_Surface;


SDL_Surface * CreateSurface()
{
    SDL_Surface * p = new SDL_Surface;
    return p;
}

void FreeSurface(SDL_Surface *p)
{
    delete p;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function< void (SDL_Surface *) > > uptr_1; 

    //how to assign a value to uptr_1 and the deleter? 

    return 0;
}
```

Is `uptr_1` correctly declared and initialized to `nullptr`?  If so, how can I assign the pointer and the deleter function?

And how can I encapsulate this:
`std::unique_ptr< SDL_Surface, std::function< void (SDL_Surface *) > >` with the deleter to not always write that line on every `SDL_Surface` I want, another typedef?

I'm just starting to learn C++11 features and this is a hard one for me.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function< void (SDL_Surface *) > > uptr_1(CreateSurface(), &::FreeSurface);`

Comment: `std::function` is a poor choice for a deleter in the general case, because its constructors can throw, but `unique_ptr`'s deleter's constructor must not throw. However, if you are only using it with a plain function pointer, it's safe.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/24251747/241631

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can initialise the `unique_ptr` with a pointer and deleter, or use `=` normally if re-assigning later:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function<void (SDL_Surface *)>> uptr_1(CreateSurface(), &FreeSurface);

uptr_1 = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function<void (SDL_Surface *)>>(CreateSurface(), &FreeSurface);
```

Refer to [suitable docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for details.

To shorten the long type, you can indeed use a type alias (`typedef` or `using`):

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, void (*)(SDL_Surface*)> Surface_ptr;

//or

using Surface_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, void (*)(SDL_Surface*)>;
```

Notice I've actually used `void (*)(SDL_Surface*)` for the deleter type. If you know you'll always pass an actual function (or stateless lambda) in, there's no reason to drag in `std::function`, which has some overhead due to type erasure.

Also, you can shorten it even further by creating a default-constructible functor for the deleter:

```
struct FreeSurface_Functor
{
  void operator() (SDL_Surface *s) const
  {
    FreeSurface(s);
  }
};
```

That way, you can make the type of your pointer `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, FreeSurface_Functor>` (possibly aliased) and you don't have to provide the deleter; it will be default-constructed:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, FreeSurface_Functor> uptr_1(CreateSurface());
```

Comment: have I to check in the custom deleter if the pointer is nullptr ? Or std::unique_ptr will not call the default deleter if the pointer is nullptr? 
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @FrameBuffer You don't have to check. `unique_ptr` is guaranteed to do the check for you, and only call the deleter if non-null. You can find stuff like that in [the docs I've linked](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr).

Comment: You might point out that the technique of defining a stateless deleter class type is preferred because quality `unique_ptr` implementations will optimize away their storage with the Empty Base Optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `decltype`:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, decltype(&FreeSurface)> uptr_1(
          CreateSurface(),
          FreeSurface
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is uptr_1 correctly declared and initialized to nullptr

Yes, a default constructed `unique_ptr` will refer to null.

> if so, how can I assign the pointer and the deleter function?

You should be constructing the `unique_ptr` with arguments

```
 std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function< void (SDL_Surface *) > > uptr_1{CreateSurface(), FreeSurface};
```

Alternatively, after the default construction you could use move assignment with a temporary

```
uptr_1 = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function< void (SDL_Surface *) > >{CreateSurface(), FreeSurface};
```

As you've suggested yourself, a type alias can help

```
using SDL_Uptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, std::function< void (SDL_Surface *)>>;
SDL_Uptr  uptr_1;
uptr_1 = SDL_Uptr{CreateSurface(), FreeSurface};
```

An intermediate function could help simplify this if it becomes repetitive (which it probably will if you make a lot of them).

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, void (*)(SDL_Surface *)>
make_sdl_ptr() {
    return std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, void (*)(SDL_Surface *)>{CreateSurface(), FreeSurface};
}
```

You could then call this with `auto uptr = make_sdl_ptr();`

Angew's answer with a DefaultConstructible deleter calling your function is also a really nice solution.