# Can't return nullptr for unique_ptr return type

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, nullptr

I am writing a wrapper for `SDL_Texture*` raw pointer which returns a `unique_ptr`.

```
using TexturePtr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, decltype(&SDL_DestroyTexture)>;

TexturePtr loadTexture(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const std::string &path) {
    ImagePtr surface =
        loadImage(path);
    if (surface) {
        return TexturePtr(
            SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface.get())
            , SDL_DestroyTexture);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

But it gives following error:

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::nullptr_t" to "std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, void (__cdecl *)(SDL_Texture *texture)>"
```

As per my understanding it's acceptable to pass a nullptr in lieu of unique_ptr. I event tried passing an empty unique_ptr on the last return:

```
return TexturePtr();
```

but get similar error during build.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Env:
compiler: Visual C++ 14.1

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to determine what deleter you want to use? The `unique_ptr` constructor that takes a `nullptr_t` is SFINAE'd out when the deleter is a pointer to function.

Comment: Better to have dedicated deleter, instead of using pointer on function. (And that would solve your issue BTW :))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `unique_ptr(nullptr_t)` constructor requires that the deleter be default constructible and that it not be a pointer type. Your deleter does not satisfy the second condition because the deleter is a pointer to function. See [[unique.ptr.single.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.ctor#1) and [[unique.ptr.single.ctor]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.ctor#4).

This restriction is a good thing because default constructing your deleter results in a `nullptr` and undefined behavior, likely resulting in a segfault, when you try to invoke the deleter.

You can change your return statement to

```
return TexturePtr{nullptr, SDL_DestroyTexture};  // or just {nullptr, SDL_DestroyTexture}
```

Alternatively, provide a deleter that satisfies the above requirements. One such option is shown in another answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252225/241631).

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Praetorian as there was a power-cut here. Sincere thanks for answering my query, providing concerned standard links and a better solution.